# C wINnet InternetConnect()

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Say I wanted to do an anonymous login, would it be to blank strings.

""  ""
?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  Can you clarify?  Do you mean "Should I accept blank strings for an anonymous login?"

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384363(VS.85).aspx), what the username and password field do is highly dependent upon the chosen protocol.  It's also highly likely that it's just as dependent upon the server you are connecting to.

For example, in FTP if you want an anonymous login, you would pass NULL to both parameters.  This will cause the API to send anonymous for both.  As long as anonymous is acceptible for an anonymous login on the server you should be in business.

Comment: I feel like a lazy hooligan..
Sorry, I really am not that much if a moocher haha.
I just wanted an answer fast and apparently overlooked my best friend..
Google :/